# How can I prevent similar queues from running at the same time?

Tags: multithreading, laravel, beanstalkd

We currently process a set of tasks using Queue workers in Laravel. When I am using multiple threads of `php artisan queue:work` jobs end up running together (async). We are using Beanstalkd as the queue driver.

The issue is that in the queue work we are polling an API that only allows one concurrent session for a particular `agent_id`. That is, only one API call with the same `agent_id` can run at a time.

We thought of spinning up multiple `php artisan queue:work` threads with a filter on the queue_name matching the `agent_id` but we have over 500 agents therefore we would need 500 threads so this is not ideal.

Is there anyway to implement a lock style feature for each `agent_id` so that if a job is already running for a particular `agent_id` it will send it back to the queue? Or are there any features of beanstalkd that would allow for this?

The other option could also be to gracefully handle the rejection from the API when the user is already logged in (and send the job back to the queue). But this could get messy and could clutter the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either run only a single worker that is capable of running the fetch-from-API job, or use some sort of external marshalling/lock service.

The options for that, may be either an internal rate limiting system, or some kind of common atomically locking system. A memcached or redis server where a worker tries to set a lock-key, and only the agent that successfully sets it, gets to work on the task. An advantage of that may be that as soon as the API request has been completed, you can remove the lock, and then while the worker processes the results, a different worker can make a new request.

Comment: Yeah I like that idea, I might use laravels built in cache function for this and set a cache on processing for that agent I'd, `Cache::put(agent_id, true)`, then check for the cache before processing. If it's already in the cache then send it back to the queue for 30 seconds.

Comment: I'd be inclined to Put to the cache (and you can't overwrite things) with an N second timeout (if it succeeds). Read back, and if the agent === me, then fetch from API, delete-cache and process.  OR, fetch from the API, and put that onto the queue, if you can.